# Font awesome knocking other divs/code blocks around in Squarespace

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, squarespace

I'm attempting to simply align some font awesome icons. In Squarespace's configuaration mode, they look fine, but when the page is reloaded they get knocked around. The image attached shows how it looks in Squarespace's config mode.

Here's the fiddle I've been using to initally set up the font awesome icons. https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/e06qzw59/

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="fixer-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="outline-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: How icons should line up]

Here's whats happening: neueda-consulting.squarespace.com/training

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The span-3 class you're adding to your colums creates a margin to the left. You'll only need to remove this class in order to make it work.

Code:

```
  <div class="row sqs-row">
    <div class="col sqs-col-3"> <!-- span-3 WAS REMOVED HERE -->
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_5416">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1461936702983_9972">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="training-name">AGILE AND ARCHITECTURE</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_18889">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-desktop" style="font-size: 65px; margin-top:22px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col sqs-col-3"> <!-- span-3 WAS REMOVED HERE -->
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_7510">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1461937219914_16038">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="training-name">PROGRAMMING LANGUAGES</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_24250">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-check" style="margin-top:13px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col sqs-col-3"><!-- span-3 WAS REMOVED HERE -->
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_29285">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1461937219914_17788">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="training-name">ANALYSIS AND MANAGEMENT</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_12489">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-database" style="font-size: 70px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col sqs-col-3"><!-- span-3 WAS REMOVED HERE -->
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_33960">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-globe" style="line-height:102px !important;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1461937219914_19354">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="training-name">ENTERPRISE PLATFORMS</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_7_1461928923800_36065">
        <div class="sqs-block-content">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="fixer-container">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="outline-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-line-chart" style="font-size:60px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually figured this out earlier. I'll elaborate below. You don't have direct access to HTML on Squarespace unless you're in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code-injection>header section of Squarespace I was creating a link to an old font awesome style sheet - so to support it in IE7.

This was overriding my existing CSS and messing wirh the current template too.

I removed it from the code-injection section and used an import statement in my CSS to still support IE7, but not override my existing style sheet.